# Magento 1.8: How to insert the customer’s email into the email templates

Tags: magento-1.8, email-templates, sales-order

How can I insert the customer’s email into the email templates for both guest and registered customers?

I came across this [answer](http://pravams.com/2010/12/23/magento-add-customer-email-address-in-email-templates/) but it seems a bit too old now as I am using Magento 1.8. The code looks different now.

The code from the answer for `app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php`,

```
foreach ($sendTo as $recipient) {
$mailTemplate-&gt;setDesignConfig(array('area'=&gt;'frontend', 'store'=&gt;$this-&gt;getStoreId()))
-&gt;sendTransactional(
$template,
Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_IDENTITY, $this-&gt;getStoreId()),
$recipient['email'],
$recipient['name'],
array(
'order'         =&gt; $this,
'billing'       =&gt; $this-&gt;getBillingAddress(),
'payment_html'  =&gt; $paymentBlock-&gt;toHtml(),
'guestemailvalue' =&gt; $recipient['email']
)
);
}
```

the code from the 1.8 for `app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php`,

```
    // Set all required params and send emails
    $mailer->setSender(Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_IDENTITY, $storeId));
    $mailer->setStoreId($storeId);
    $mailer->setTemplateId($templateId);
    $mailer->setTemplateParams(array(
            'order'        => $this,
            'billing'      => $this->getBillingAddress(),
            'payment_html' => $paymentBlockHtml
        )
    );
    $mailer->send();
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tealau,
for getting new order email goto

```
app/locale/yourlanguae/template/email/sales/
```

**magento used different different email template for  guest and register**

find  and here you find list order email and  you can getusing

```
 {{htmlescape var=$order.getCustomerEmail()}}
```

Comment: Thanks Amit. do I have to put that in the curly brackets like this `{{var order.getBillingAddress().email()}}`?

Comment: just tested it but no email printed in the email at all :(

Comment: can you tell me  on which email template you have using

Comment: is neworder  email ?

Comment: guest email template...

Comment: yes the new order email template

Comment: can you try this {{htmlescape myemail=$order.getCustomerEmail()}}

Comment: can need work on order_new.html and order_new_guest.html

Comment: yes it now works with ` {{htmlescape var=$order.getCustomerEmail()}} `

Comment: just for testing.... can you try this {{htmlescape myemail=$order.getCustomerEmail()}}

Comment: what about the invoice template, can I use that as well?

Comment: check this on  both   guest and register customer

Comment: sure ... you can check on invoice two template